# Is there an opposite of IndexOf()? Perhaps NotIndexOf()?

Tags: c#

If *myStr* is supposed to contain 0's and 1's, how can I search this string for anything that is not a 0 or 1?

For example:

```
string myStr = "1001g101";

if (myStr.IndexOf(NOT "0") != -1 && myStr.IndexOf(NOT "1") != -1) {
    Console.Write("String contains something that isn't 0 or 1!");
}
```

My reason for doing this is not wanting to do a full ASCII character map and have it check each character against all ASCII characters, it seems way too inefficient. If I have to check each character and ensure 0 or 1, that will work, but is there a better way?

I am not good with Regex, but I suspect that may hold my answer.

Comment: You could try it with foreach(var c in str) .... This will be fast because C# does optimize the iterator in a special way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or use LINQ:

```
if (myStr.Any(c => c != '0' && c != '1'))
    ....
```

Comment: Wouldn't recommend it, it'll probably be too slow.

Comment: If you're trying to compare LINQ to regex, there are no blanket rules. Test and see.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with LINQ, like Michael Gunter already did with his answer, but I would make it a little more complex, to make it easier to write/read and faster:

```
var desiredCharacters = new HashSet<char>() { '0', '1' };
var input = "1011001010110";

if(input.Any(x => !desiredCharacters.Contains(x)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input string contains something that is not defined in desiredCharacters collection.");
}
```

I would say, the bigger `desiredCharacters` collection is the more performance gain you get agains standard `||` comparison.

And because you can easily modify `desiredCharacters` collection content, you can add multiple characters without additional `||`, which would make the whole thing much less readable.

**Edit**

You can get the same results with `All` method:

```
if(!input.All(desiredCharacters.Contains))
{
    //(...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use regex. The following regex pattern should do the trick

```
^[01]*$
```

A sample code would be:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(myStr , @"^[01]*$");

if (!match.Success)
    Console.Write("String contains something that isn't 0 or 1!");
```

Comment: If using regex, it would need to be something like `^[01]*$`. Without the `^` and `$`, it would match things like 'g01' or '10foo'.

Comment: The message should say: _There is no `0` and `1` at all in the string_ to match your current regex. To get what OP wants use `@"^[01]*$"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use iteration, something like this, running in something like O( *m* log *n* ) time, where *m* is the length of string `s` and *n* the length of string `chars`:

```
public static int NotIndexOf( this string s , string chars )
{
  char[] orderedChars = chars.ToCharArray() ;
  Array.Sort( orderedChars ) ;

  int index = -1 ;
  for ( int i = 0 ; index < 0 && i < s.Length ; ++i )
  {
    int p = Array.BinarySearch(orderedChars, s[i] ) ;
    if ( p < 0 )
    {
      index = i ;
    }
  }
  return index ;
}
```

With a regular expression, you just need to construct the desired negative character class. On the other hand, save for constructing the negative character set, it's pretty straightforward. Here I'm building the character set using unicode code point escapes (`\uXXXX`) so as to avoid having to deal with characters that have the potential to be special in the context of a character set (`]`, `^`, `-` and `\` just for starters).

```
public static int NotIndexOf( this string s , string chars )
{
  StringBuilder regexString = new StringBuilder(3+6*chars.Length) ;
  regexString.Append("[^") ;
  foreach ( char c in chars.Distinct() )
  {
    regexString.AppendFormat( @"\u{0:X4}" , (ushort)c ) ;
  }
  regexString.Append("]") ;

  Regex rxCharSet = new Regex( regexString , Regex ) ;
  Match m         = rxCharSet.Match(s) ;

  return m.Success ? m.Index : -1 ;
}
```